# Line Integral Convolution (LIC) Requirements

Tags: python, visualization, integral-equations

I'm trying to plot some vector fields using LIC technique.
More specifically, I'm using the Python [solution](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/LineIntegralConvolution) for this kind of plot.

Before applying that approach, I was plotting my vectors as quiver. This give me results like this:

[image]

However, for large data, this technique is not recommended because the larger the data, the more compressed the arrows will be, and, consequently, the plot will get confusing and not readable.

Using LIC, however, I got the opposite result.
I get a poor resolution for my plot and it is hard to understand the flow behavior.

[image]

Both plots are from a 61 x 61 vector field.

I really would like to use LIC, however, I'm wondering if there is a data size requirement to get good results.

Is there an approach to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use quiver but skip some rows/columns while plotting? Like examples [5 and 3  here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html).

Comment: Yes, this definitely is a possible solution. However, I was asked to use LIC somehow.

Comment: Another thing is that I'm merging this plot with another information, such as sources, sinks, saddles... Using LIC a get a "clear" plot.

Comment: Is it possible to share your vector field data ?

Comment: Of course, @SAAD. (: However, I didn't save this data, so I generated a new one (and edited the question images). Here is the code (from Scipy) and images: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ped312ur604357r/AACQGloHDAy8I2C6HITFzjqza?dl=0

Comment: I'd love to have seen how your data was created @pceccon - one of the best reasons for putting the code in the question is that links rot, as this one (understandably) has. If you do have the code, please consider putting it into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that there is a size requirement to get a good resolution
I'm not sure if that is the properly way to solve this, but it worked for me.

What I did was to interpolate the x and y components of the vector field. Talking about Python, this can be done using the `scipy.ndimage.zoom` function.

As an example, I had this vector field (100 x 100):

[image]

Which results in this LIC image:

[image]

Using an interpolation with factor 4, I'm able to get this result from LIC:

[image]

(:

Answer (score 2):

LIC is very good for visualizing such fields, but what is the texture warped here? First of all, use LIC with white noise in the very beginning. You could then try Perlin noise and similar. There are also other variants of information, such as the coherence directions, which would give you a better idea of the flow field. You could check out [this work of mine](http://tbirdal.me/downloads/tolga-birdal-flow-lic-icip-2010.pdf) for an interesting application.

Comment: This texture was generated with a LIC procedure from Scipy, which can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ped312ur604357r/AACQGloHDAy8I2C6HITFzjqza?dl=0

Comment: Your link is not working anymore.

Comment: Updated the link.